# Rails 4: display spinner with javascript on form submit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

In my Rails 4 app, which uses Turbolinks, I have the following form:

```
<%= form_for [@calendar, @post], html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
[...]
  <div class="actions" id="post_submit_before_spinner">
    <%= f.submit @post.new_record? ? "CREATE POST" : "UPDATE POST", :id => :post_submit %>
  </div>
  <div class="spinner" id="post_submit_spinner">
    <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i> Please wait...
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I would like to display the spinner currently in the `post_submit_spinner` div with JavaScript when the form is submitted.

I have this in `app/assets/javascripts/posts.coffee`:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#post_submit_spinner').hide()
  return

$(document).getElementById('post_submit').on click() ->
  $('#post_submit_spinner').show()
  return
```

The spinner is hidden on page load — which is what I want — but it does not show up when a user submits the form with the button in the `post_submit_before_spinner` div.

Any idea what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem with the following code in `app/assets/javascripts/posts.coffee`:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#post_submit_spinner').hide()

$(document).ready ->
  $("#post_submit_before_spinner").click ->
    $('#post_submit_spinner').show()
    return
  return
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest adding the click listener definition inside the `$.ready` function call (since `post_submit` element could not be present yet) as follows:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#post_submit_spinner').hide()
  $('#post_submit').on click() ->
    $('#post_submit_spinner').show()
    return
  return
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see what you mean and it makes sense. I implemented the code and it does not seem to work yet. I get the following error in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).getElementById is not a function`. Any idea?

Comment: @ThibaudClement, good to know ... if it helped, then select as best answer :)

Comment: Well, as mentioned in my comment, it is not working yet. Can't accept the answer if it did not solve the issue.

Comment: The jquery object returned by `$(document)` does not have a `getElementById` function.  Use `$('#post_submit')` instead of `$(document).getElementById('post_submit')`.

Comment: @ThibaudClement see my edit. Thanks to ihaztehcodez for pointing it out